How to create a quantum algorithm to determine unknown coefficients in a linear function
I am trying to solve the following practice question shown below. I am stuck on part (c) where I must design a quantum algorithm to solve the stated problem. I can tell that the solution is probably to do something like $\text{QFT} \rightarrow U_f \rightarrow \text{QFT}$, but I'm stuck because I cannot identify what the starting state should be. In particular, let's suppose we start with the state $|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$ and use $\text{QFT}$ to manufacture the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_3} |x\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$. We could now apply the oracle to get the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_3} |x\rangle \otimes |f(x)\rangle$. But at this point I am stuck - I do not know how to apply the result of part (b) in order to get the next step.
Note that in part (b) I calculated the basis of eigenstates $|x\rangle \otimes |\xi_{f(x)}\rangle \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}_n\}$ for $U_f$ where the eigenvalues are $\omega^{f(x)}$.
How should we proceed to solve this problem?

